# How to detect a window has been maximized?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

Does anyone know the WM_MESSAGE that is sent when a window has been maximized (either by the maximize button being pressed in the title bar, or by double clicking the title bar?)

Is there a windows message for the maximize button being pressed?

Win32/C++, thanks.

Comment: It's unusual for this information to be terribly useful... what is this for? (To correctly save maximized state of window for later restoring, use `GetWindowPlacement`/`SetWindowPlacement` rather than, say, `GetWindowRect`/`SetWindowPos`. To remove maximize button, omit the `WS_MAXIMIZEBOX` flag in `CreateWindow`. To limit window size, handle `WM_SIZING`. And so on.) With apologies for trying to second-guess a simple question, as I hate it when people do that.

Comment: I have disabled both WM_PAINT and WM_ERASEBKGRND from my program to be able to display un-double buffered images without having them flicker. I needed to know the window message that was sent on window maximize because after I clicked my maximize button, the images did not appear where I wanted them to (so I wanted to handle the maximize button event to have the images placed where I wanted them on press).

Comment: I bet you forgot the `CS_VREDEAW | CS_HREDRAW` styles.

Comment: The problem persists whether I change those styles to null, or not (I tried both). I have no idea why WM_MOVE is being called on WM_SIZE(window maximized). Though, I would guess the window IS moving when being maximized (kinda).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get the [WM_SIZE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632646%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message with the value SIZE_MAXIMIZED in wParam

**Edit**

The @jamesdlin comment bellow called my atention to [WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632652%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation, which states (emphasis mine):

> **Remarks**
>   By default, the DefWindowProc function sends the WM_SIZE and WM_MOVE messages to the window. **The WM_SIZE and WM_MOVE messages are not sent** if an application handles the WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED message without calling DefWindowProc. It is more efficient to perform any move or size change processing during the WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED message without calling DefWindowProc.

Thanks james!

Comment: Normally, you would be right, however, because I am handling the WM_MOVE message, for some reason, when the window is maximized, a WM_MOVE message is being sent instead of WM_SIZE. I will accept this answer because it is in fact the one I was looking for, but I don't know why WM_MOVE is being called on on a window maximize event.

Comment: Note that `WM_SIZE` won't be sent if the window handles and consumes `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED`.

Comment: @jamesdlin I updated the question to include a quote from documentation about that. Thanks!

Comment: @JamesDiaz hopefully it explains what you know by experience. :)

Answer (score 1):

I dealt with this recently, and the approach I settled on was to check `IsZoomed` in response to `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED`, comparing its result to the previous one to detect when a transition occurs, and then to forward `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` to the default window procedure.

If you have complete control over the message handling in your application and know that there isn't (and won't ever be) a `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` handler that suppresses `WM_MOVE`/`WM_SIZE`, then you should be able to handle it directly in a `WM_SIZE` handler as described in [jachguate's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13485303/179715).